# Select all from a table, where 2 columns are Distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I have a table of deals, I need to return the entire table but I need the title and the price to be distinct, as there is quite a few double ups, I've put in an example scenario below

```
Col ID || Col Title || Col Price || Col Source
a b c d
a b c b
b a a c
b a a 1
```

Expected result:

```
a b c d
b a a c
```

I'm not sure whether or not to use distinct or group by here, any suggestions would be appreciated

Cheers

Scott

=======================

Looking at some of your suggestions I'm going to have to rethink this, Thanks guys

Comment: Why did you want abcd and not abcb?

Comment: How would you know which `Source` to use since there would be 2 for each in your example?

Comment: You can't have "entire table" and "title and the price to be distinct" *at the same time*

Comment: THink about it now I'd need to factor in the a third column too, Ok i'm gona have to rethink this

Answer (score 1):

This will arbitrarily pick one of the rows for each distinct (price,title) pair

```
;WITH myCTE AS
(
    SELECT
       *,
       ROWNUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Price, Title ORDER BY Source) AS rn
    FROM
       MyTable
) 
SELECT
    *
FROM
    myCTE
WHERE
    rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by, but to return only title and price, ID and source would have to be ignored

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for entire table but in your sample output you have lost two Records and thus losing the value of 'Col Source'.

```
a b c b
b a a 1
```

Group By will help you write very simple query

```
select id, title, price, source from table group by title, price
```

Answer (score 0):

A `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` usually generate the same query plan, so performance should be the same across both query constructs. `GROUP BY` should be used to apply aggregate operators to each group. If all you need is to remove duplicates then use `DISTINCT`. If you are using sub-queries execution plan for that query varies so in that case you need to check the execution plan before making decision of which is faster.

You should go for the GROUP BY as the entire columns required in your resultset. However, the DISTINCT will return only unique list of specific column.

```
SELECT ID, Title, Price, Source 
FROM table as t 
GROUP BY Title, Price
```